# How to get a subproject from commit list

Tags: python, git, gitlab, repository, sha

I'm trying to get all the commits from a GitLab repository, and it was all going smoothly and fine.

Because of another unrelated problem, I had to update my python from 3.7 to 3.9. Since then, every time I run my program I run this specific error:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError
> SHA b'7e944e65ee1a628e7ba0d53aac7a7bb13e79fe53' could not be resolved, git returned: b'7e944e65ee1a628e7ba0d53aac7a7bb13e79fe53 missing'

Meanwhile, I discovered that this specific commit that is causing the error, besides modifying a file, also has this:

> Subproject commit 7e944e65ee1a628e7ba0d53aac7a7bb13e79fe53

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

My code is as follows:

```
try:
        repo = Repository(repo_name).traverse_commits()
    except:
        print("Repository not found")
        exit(0)

for commit in repo:

    for f in commit.modified_files: #(error here)
         #(get info)
```

Comment: Probably not, I have no clue where that b is coming from... The code and the commit are exactly as I added there and the same problem is occurring in other repositories aswell. Plus, it started only when I updated python so I may need some sort of turnaround...

Comment: That's something that I believe is standardized since it's pydriller retrieving the commit from GitLab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "subproject commit" (as printed this way by Git itself) is actually a *gitlink*, which is a very specific kind of item stored in one of two places:

- in Git's index, as a path name and `mode 160000` plus a hash ID; or
- in a *tree* object, as a component name, `mode 160000`, and hash ID.

The hash ID in this case is the `7e944e65ee1a628e7ba0d53aac7a7bb13e79fe53` value, which is not itself a byte string but would often be represented *as* a byte string in Python.

The trick here is that this is the hash ID of a commit that *should* exist in *some other Git repository*.  Unless the "other" Git repository is in fact this Git repository—a rare but not unheard-of situation<sup>1</sup>—it *will not* exist in *this* Git repository.  You therefore can't look it up using *this* Git repository.

To get the commit, you must:

1. Clone the other Git repository, if you have not yet done so: you'll find its URL in the `.gitmodules` file in the commit that contains this gitlink.  If this gitlink's path is *P*, you must read the `.gitmodules` file and find each `[submodule "name"]` entry and under that entry find each `url` and `path` value.  If the `path` value matches *P*, the URL value is the URL for the submodule.
2. Now that the submodule is cloned, attempt to load the specified commit *from* the *other* Git repository.  It may not exist: if that's the case, this is simply a bad / invalid gitlink, and cannot be used.  If the specified commit *does* exist, that's the commit that this superproject commit says *should* be checked out, if this particular commit is also to be checked out.

Note that no commit contains any modified files:

> ```
> for f in commit.modified_files:
> ```

At a guess, this refers to the [pydriller](https://pydriller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html) library, which provides such a field.  The problem here is that *Git* doesn't have this.  Instead, Git commits have *snapshots and metadata*.  One can synthetically compute a list of "modified files" by obtaining not only *this* commit's set of files in its snapshot, but also some previous commit's set of files, in *its* snapshot, and then comparing the two.

Computing this list—the "modified files" implied by comparing a commit to its (single) parent—*is* very useful, so both Pydriller and Git itself have a way to do that: in Git you run can run `git show` or `git diff-tree` for instance, while Pydriller simply Just Does It.  But if you're not *careful* with this synthesized information, you will be led astray, just as you were here.  It's important to realize that this list of modified files is an illusion, albeit a useful one.  In some situations, it's less useful than others.  When working with submodules, a difference of the form *old gitlink was <hash1>, new gitlink is <hash2>* is just that: a difference in *gitlinks*.  It's up to you to realize that these are both gitlinks and hence both refer to some commit that should (but may or may not, at this point) exist in some other repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>If a repository refers to itself in a gitlink, this is a bit recursive and you may need to use even more care here.  The only case I know of where it's common is with GitHub Pages, where people will insert a gitlink to the original repository, but carefully store different commits in different commit-chains so that the recursion terminates immediately.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you say, so the only way would be to open both repositories (the current and the one referenced) with pydriller? I know you said I could use git diff-tree, but since pydriller clones the repository at the beginning to a temp dir and in the end it deletes the clone Idk if it would be very useful...

Comment: I don't know the usage details for pydriller, but if it does its own cloning, it probably ought to have an option for "following" a gitlink (with all the complexity that this brings).